# DB structure to handle chat groups similar to Telegram/FB Messenger

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently doing a chat app where a user could join multiple chat groups, something similar to what Telegram and Facebook Messenger has. Pretty straight forward. We're mainly using Firebase database for storing the chat groups and message details.

Sample DB structure:

To only get the chat groups a user has:

```
root/
users/
  chatGroups/
    $uid/
      $chatGroupId: true
```

We then get the details of the chat group from a different node, same with the latest chat message in that group:

```
root/
chatGroups/
  entries/
    $groupId/
      group details here...
  messages/
    $groupId/
      $messageId/
        message details here..
```

Everything above  to get the data for a single group item that looks something like this:

[image]

All works fine. We initially get at most 5 chat groups at first, then just sort the list. The problem lies where we have to listen for updates for the chat groups -- *group with the most recent chat message would go to top of the list*.

The structure we have listens only to the list of groups the specific user has -- we could detect groups joined (`onChildAdded`) and left (`onChildRemoved`) by the user, but it doesn't contain the timestamp we need to sort the chat group list by the most recent changes timestamp.

Has anyone tried this similar behavior with Firebase before (we're doing a client for both Android and Web -- Javascript)? Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Let me know if you need some relevant details to make things clearer.

Comment: In a case like this, I'd consider keeping the `lastUpdated` timestamp in each user's index if chat groups, so `$chatGroupId: 1508508569108`. Depending on the number of members in a group, It may be a quite expensive fan-out operation to update those timestamps. But I don't immediately see many other options.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Puf. Yeah. We thought of the same thing. We're expecting at most 300 users in a chat group, so yeah, it would be expensive to write to each one.

Comment: That indeed sounds a bit too much. How many groups will a user on average be in? Because if that is smaller, you could also keep an index of the group ids for each user, load the metadata/lastmodified for each group, and order them client-side.

Comment: My guess estimate would be 10-20 groups per user, we also have an admin-like user, which could go beyond 50 to possibly 100. Currently, we went with just having directly attaching the user and pulling all the data. For the client side, I went ahead and enabled disk persistence, hopefully it would help lessen the calls (no repeat calls). But if ever we do find it really giving the user a bad UX (longer wait time, etc.), we're planning to go ahead and implement a manual refresh instead (pull down refresh), which we think is the least expensive workaround so far.

Comment: I'd consider keeping listeners on those 10-20 groups in that case, which means you only get traffic if the timestamp for a group changes - more likely a stable flow over time.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no auto-created metadata in Firebase about when a child was added, updated or deleted and also because those operations doesn't contain the information you are searching for, you need to create your own mechanism by adding the local timestamp for each operation or by [writing a server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps).

There is another approach in which you can use denormalization. Add those chats to a new created section named `uxChats`. The chats will need to contain only the `text message` and the `timestamp`. If you are using [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) then you can reverse the order just using this lines of code:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

Latest chat goes on top.

Hope it helps AL.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks. We're already aware of the behaviors and the usual mechanisms. I was aiming for someone to suggest a structure that would best utilize Firebase DB's behavior so we could produce the UX -- *latest chat auto goes on top*.

Comment: Updated the answer with a new idea.